# How to implement convolutional RNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, suppose I have an image, and I would like to apply the same convolutional kernel to it multiple times. For example, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
for i in range(5):
    output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights, [1,1,1,1]), bias))
```

But this runs out of memory very quickly if I have many loops. I think this is because the system is allocating enough memory to hold the entire sequence at once.

What is an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this on GPU, and if so what GPU are you running it on? Also, how big is your input image? Remember that you _have_ to keep the sequence around so you can do back propagation to get the gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm running it on GPU, a 12GB Titan X. Input image is 1024x512, but I suppose I could down sample this. You are absolutely right about needing to keep the sequence around for back propagation for gradients. Thus, you are thinking that this is in fact the right way to go?

Comment: Indeed. Your approach looks ok. If you so run out of memory, ping back with the sizes and number of time steps you are trying to run.

Comment: I see. I guess my number of time steps is too high.. I'll have to reformulate the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The way tensorflow works is as follows:

When you create any operation, even if this operation is not used, it will not be destroyed. Therefore, through each iteration, you are creating 3 operations. So after 5 iterations, you end up with 15 operations. So in reality, this is not how to apply the same convolutional kernel to the input. So you should rather create the whole graph first. That is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[...], name='input_frames')
weights: tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, 128], stddev=1e-1, dtype=tf.float32, name='weights1'))
output = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights, [1,1,1,1]), bias))

for i in range(5):
    sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: "your_image"})
```

Hope this helps.